# show remote image on Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am using mysql database, i have a web site. So now i decided to create a mobile application. But i have some image in ftp, and their path saved as a varchar in mysql.

I connect to mysql remotely in Android app. But i dont know which is the best way to show image on Android app.

I have 2 way to show it. First one is i can get an image path and show on an url in image view or the other one is i saved that images blob file in mysql and get the base64 encoded text and show. But which is the better way ?

Comment: Do both. And maitain both solutions. You will be happy.

Comment: @greenapps can you give me show url image view example ? I tried some methods on internet but doesnot work for me

Comment: No. Thats not the way it goes here. Assigning an image from an url to a imageview is a very common task. Code for it you can find multiple times on this site or other.

Comment: thank you, i decided to image show with volley :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has released an awesome library that handles HTTP requests and its main purpose is literally simplify developers life when they need to manage a huge amount of web requests, providing ***image caching*** solutions and avoiding the problems of concurrent programming, thread syncronization etc...

I'm talking about [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

This great solution is exactly the solution to your problem, why? It's because it exposes a clear way to request remote image resources and caching them directly inside the app storage, without the inconvenient of using mobile network each time you open the app, refresh a fragment/activity or add a new element to a listview object.

This is done by implementing an [image request](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-image) method.

So, I think you should store your images on disk and save just their path inside the database, and then, from the app, make a request to your server, **Volley** will take care of getting the image and raising a callback when the request has been completed.

Simple and clear.

Comment: i use volley but i dont know image caching solution. Thank you very much, its perfect for me :)))